# Using Br tag in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, mobile, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin Forms. I use a BoxView for making spaces between lines but I don't know if I'm doing right. What is the proper way to using a br tag in Xamarin ? Is there an alternative way for it? I'm using this:

```
<StackLayout>
  <Label Text="Line 1"></Label>
  <BoxView HeightRequest="100"></BoxView>
  <Label Text="Line 2"></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

---

Thank you for the replies, for a conclusion; I thought the simpliest alternative should be like this, 
and normally, I'll use a Grid, for spacing.

```
<StackLayout>
  <Label Text="10"></Label>
  <StackLayout HeightRequest="100"></StackLayout>
  <Label Text="20"></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are already using a StackLayout, you can set 'spacing' between each element in the Stackayout, example :

```
<StackLayout Spacing="10">
```

Some other options can be found in the Xamarin Forum though... https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/29700/label-and-n

Comment: This will give the same spaces for each line in StackLayout but okey this should be useful  when trying multiple StackLayouts and then I can give custom spaces.

Comment: True, depends a bit on the setup... Look at the forum link I provided it has more options. Just need to see what fits best for your problem, the question was a bit generic ;)

Comment: By the way, this not worked but this worked: <StackLayout HeightRequest="10"></StackLayout>

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this depending on your requirements.

You can set the `Margin` property on your `Label`, also you can set the `Spacing` on your `StackLayout` which tells the `StackLayout` to put some space between the items in it.

Another way would be to change your `StackLayout` to a `Grid`. With this you have some more fine grained control because you can not only set the `Spacing` like on a `StackLayout` but you can also play with the row height and column widths. Within the `Grid` columns and rows you can nest a `StackLayout` for more control on how they should behave in there.

For more information on the Grid check the extensive guide in the [Xamarin Documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid/).

Answer (score 1):

```
you can follow the example bellow or use [GRID ][1]
        StackLayout  linesSTK= new StackLayout {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            HorizontalOptions =LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            Children = {
                new Label { Text = "Line 1" },
                new Label { Text = "Line 2" },
                new Label { Text = "Line 3" }
            }
        };
```